# Remove Double Quotes only from Numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove all double quotes using regex in CSV file 
if its coming between double quotes. Currently I am using following regex to do this : only from numbers and not from alphabets.. 
The input is

```
"000027679","ROMANO","CRYSTAL","S","FT","19990706","19990706","A",,"006901",
```

I tried this regex expression

```
string newcontent = Regex.Replace(contents, @"[\""]", "");
```

but this is removing all the double quotes which I don't want.
I want to remove only double quotes from numbers.

Comment: `string newcontent = Regex.Replace(contents, @"\"(\d+)\"", "$1");`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with captured group in regex, use regex **[`"(\d+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/pH4lI8/1)** and replace it with captured value

---

**CODE:**

```
string contents="\"000027679\",\"ROMANO\",\"CRYSTAL\",\"S\",\"FT\",\"19990706\",\"19990706\",\"A\",,\"006901\"";
string newcontent = Regex.Replace(contents,@"""(\d+)""", "$1");<hr>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
000027679,"ROMANO","CRYSTAL","S","FT",19990706,19990706,"A",,006901
```

Comment: nice speedy regex algorithm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookahead and lookbehind. means that double quotes only matches when the preceding characters or next characters are digits.

```
string newcontent = Regex.Replace(contents, @"(?<=\d+\d)[""]|[""](?=\d+\d)", "");
```

Comment: And when it's "1asd3" this will also remove them?

Comment: nice catch let me see what can i do.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen fixed it. note that regex in c# works with lookbehind and qualifier. but some regex engines may not work with it.